# I dislike the current head of my dynasty, can I arrange an accident for him?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

The current ruler of my dynasty is a bit of an idiot. His heir shows much more promise; is there a way to get rid of my current ruler?

Comment: Nowhere near surefire, but you could keep organizing hunts, as a lot of those events give you some minor chance of dying. And, of course, to the computer, it seems 1% chance of death == 80% chance of death...

Comment: +1 for the wording of the title, because 'Accidents' do happen... all the time. >:)

Comment: RIP [tag:murder]

Comment: several options...  have a very negative opinion of some family member, like your wife, hopefully they'll start a plot to kill you.  Another thing, put yourself at the head of every battle (and try to lose them), like rebellions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just keep throwing him in harms way. Hunts, get into as many fights as possible, piss off the natives, go crusading at every chance. That should up the odds nicely. There's gamey ways to do it like Rodolfo stated, but who would do that? ;)

Answer (score 11):

ways I do that (legally):

- Really mistreat someone (like your wife), hopefully they'll start a plot to kill you.
- Put yourself in every battle you do, try to lose them ;)

In a more 'cheaty' way, you probably can load the game as one of your counts/dukes and select the plot to kill the liege :)  then go back to yourself and wait until they succeed

Answer (score 9):

One of the most reliable ways is to try and assassinate someone with very high intrigue. They will discover your assassin, and then they are very likely to send an assassin after you. If they fail, or don't send an assassin, just try again. Conveniently, after you die the reputation hit from assassinations disappear.

Answer (score 5):

You can also commit suicide. This option is available in your decision tab, if your character has the "depressed" trait. I'm uncertain when this was introduced; I don't think it was possible in 1.0.

Comment: Is having the depressed trait the only way you get the suicide option? How does a character get depressed?

Comment: There might be other ways, I don't know. When I hover over it, it simply lists "(*) is depressed" as the only requirement. My character got depressed after his first born son died, but I believe there are random triggers for it.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to get your heir on the throne is for your current character to be forced to give up the throne as a result of surrendering in an excommunication war or a war to dispose of a tyrannical liege.

In the case of the latter here are some ways to get your vassals motivated to stand up against your rule:

- revoke their titles
- imprison them
- execute said prisoners

I'm not sure what the odds are they won't start a war for independence as opposed to a war to depose of their liege, but if your current ruler is a bit of a douche to start with it's another in-character way to get what you're after.

Answer (score -1):

tryusing console command.

1. Hit tilde ("~") key
2. type "charinfo 1"and hit enter (this is to enable the game tooltip to show more information)
3. Hover to your character, memorize his character ID (strings of numbers, like 543524)
4. type "kill -yourcharacterID-", hit enter. Voila!

Comment: While this does kill the character, it doesn't do so via arranging an in-game accident. Captain Kirk would approve, though.